# Gradle Composite Build: How to configure Tasks for all included builds

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, composite, precompiled, gradle-multi-project-build

I am new to gradle composite builds. I have a multi-project build that uses precompiled script plugins in order to have tasks configured for all projects that include the plugin. Now I want to port that functionality to a composite build setup.

The screenshots below show how the current multi-project build works:
[image: java-precompiled-script-plugin]
This java precompiled script plugin (/buildSrc/.../java-conventions.gradle.kts) configures the "JavaCompile" tasks (i.e. sourceCompatability, targetCompatability...).
[image]
This kotlin precompiled script plugin imports the java conventions plugin and configures the "KotlinCompile" tasks.
[image]
Applying the the kotlin conventions plugin to project "test" automagically sets up my project with the proper "JavaCompile" and "KotlinCompile" configuration as shown above.

I have read the official docs and tutorials on gradle composite builds. Still, I dont know the proper way how to do this with composite builds. Do I have to write standalone plugins for this? If so, can you provide a POC code snippet? Any advice is greatly appreciated!